# What's the first movie to show newspaper spinning towards screen?

Tags: first-appearance

In old movies, they used to show newspaper spinning towards screen like this:

Here is the example from *The Godfather (1972)*:

[image]

Comment: This trope goes back to at least the 1930's - https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Spinning_Paper

Comment: This is obviously a first appearance question: why does it get closed as trivia?

Comment: Just because it fits into a specific tag does not mean it isn't trivia. Why is this **important**, frankly IMO it's not so it's trivia? Honestly I dislike [tag:first-appearance] questions except for truly unique/unusual issues but that's just me.

Comment: Sometimes 'first appearance' questions get a really good press; other times… not so much. IDK why. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51301/first-example-of-ringing-in-ears-sound-design

Comment: @Paulie_D Counterargument: because you don't think it's important it's trivia? :) I realize they are not mutually exclusive, but closing this as trivia suggests the *nature* of the first-appearance question is trivial (which it still might be, but something we'd have to concede).

Comment: Voting is subjective so yes, if I don't think it's important then *to me* it IS trivia. I'm not saying ALL first appearance are trivial but in my experience the vast majority are.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude, but my initial remark was about closing, not downvoting. I'm obviously not saying I disagree with your reason for downvoting this.

Comment: Downvoting/Close Voting - still based on my opinion.